# getSupportLoaderManager() is undefined for the type MainActivity

Tags: android

i have this code in java:

```
    private void doSearch(String query){
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("query", query);
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(0, data, this);
}

private void getPlace(String query){
    Bundle data = new Bundle();
    data.putString("query", query);
    getSupportLoaderManager().restartLoader(1, data, this);
}
```

This code in `MainActivity`.

> The method getSupportLoaderManager() is undefined for the type
>   MainActivity i use minimum sdk version 8,

can you help me?

Comment: What does your MainActivity extend??

Comment: @Raghunandan Activity

Comment: add support library v7

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The method getSupportLoaderManager() is undefined for the type
>   MainActivity i use minimum sdk version 8

You need to extend `FragmentActivity` instead of `Activity`.

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportLoaderManager()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity.html#getSupportLoaderManager%28%29)